# Eclipse C++ Not Working "Launch Failed. Binary Not Found" or "The selection cannot be launched and there are no recent launches"

Tags: c++, eclipse

I recently installed eclipse oxygen to program C++. However, I cannot get it to work. I downloaded it from [this](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/oxygen/2/eclipse-cpp-oxygen-2-win32-x86_64.zip) page. Then, I unzipped the folder and ran eclipsec.exe and built a project called Test1. Here are the steps: right click->new->C/C++ project->C++ Managed Build->Project Name Test1->Hello World C++ Project->next->next->next->finish. Then I click the green run button in the top middle of the screen, and it gives me an error of "Launch Failed. Binary not found." Please help! I have been looking for a solution for days. Yes, my binary parser is PE Windows Parser, and yes I have built the project.
[image]
my code:

```
//============================================================================
// Name        : Test3.cpp
// Author      : 
// Version     :
// Copyright   : Your copyright notice
// Description : Hello World in C++, Ansi-style
//============================================================================

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Erm, you haven't built your project. The error says make not found. make is used to build your project. Probably you should do what the error says and put make on your PATH.

Comment: I don't know what that means. I just got Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Open project Properties -> C/C++ Build > Tool Chain Editor and select 'MinGw Gcc'

Hope you have enivronment variables set, if not add this *C:\MinGW (your path)* =

```
MINGW_HOME   C:\MinGW 
PATH   C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin
```

Comment: You may well be right, but I'm curious how you know the OP has MinGW?

Comment: as he is using windows

Comment: What about cygwin? Maybe he has neither MinGW or cygwin?

Comment: @Jevin by my path do you mean my code? I am bad at programming

Comment: No, not your code. Your PATH is an *envionment variable*. It's a Windows setting. Open a command window (you know what that is?) and type PATH, and then report what that shows.

Comment: @Indigo2003 no, the compiler (if you didnt change this, the default is the one mentioned in my post)

Comment: @john PATH=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Users\Rick\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;

Comment: OK well like Jevin says you need to add the build tools (like the compiler, the linker, make etc) to your PATH. Assuming you do have MinGW installed then something like what Javid said would be correct. But you really need to read up on how to install Eclipse for C++ and understand what it's telling you.

Comment: I am very new to eclipse. Shouldn't I just be able to download the zip folder, run the exe, and create a project?  What else do I have to do?

Comment: No, eclipse does not include a C++ compiler. You need to install the C++ compiler separately. The two main choices are cygwin and MinGW. Hard to find good documentation but here's a stack overflow question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753541/how-do-i-set-up-c-c-on-eclipse-in-windows

Comment: But really on Windows I would go for Visual Studio every time, unless you have very specific requirements

Comment: Ok thanks. I actually have visual studio installed, but have no idea how to use it. I'll try to install MinGW too though