# C++: can't get eclipse to work. I need a library

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

So I downloaded eclipse, and put in this simple "Hello World" code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And this is my build error message:

Error: Program "make" not found in PATH
PATH=[C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin]

Note that this is like the 5th thing I downloaded, and each time I updated the Environment Path and such, to the bin folder, where the gcc.exe is, but it still can't find "make."

I already downloaded MinGW, W64DevKit, llvm-minwg, etc. So I'll take suggestions on what to download...

Comment: [Eclipse C++ Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54999347/eclipse-c-setup) and [How do I set up C/C++ on Eclipse in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753541/how-do-i-set-up-c-c-on-eclipse-in-windows) and [How to run a c/c++ application in eclipse for c/c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31642008/how-to-run-a-c-c-application-in-eclipse-for-c-c)

Comment: make is not a library.  It is a gnu utility and part of the GNU toolchain.  It is looking for make.exe, locate that. It may be where gcc.exe is but that is not really the point - that is not what it is looking for (yet).  No amount of downloading is going to fix a misconfiguration if you already have make.  Sounds like you may have downloaded multiple toolchains already, which may not be wise.  They probably all include make.

Answer (score 0):

For MinGW make is: mingw32-make.exe
The simplest solution in your case would be:

1. copy mingw32-make.exe => make.exe
2. make sure that make.exe is in your PATH
   Probably this post well help:
   [How to compile makefile using MinGW?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11772602/how-to-compile-makefile-using-mingw)

Another option:

1. File - New - Project
2. C++ Project, Next
3. Makefile project - Hello World C++ Makefile project - MinGW GCC
4. Finish